# Content Delivery API multiple Page response/Content Search API Filter Criteria

Tags: episerver, optimizely, episerver-find

In my application ,I have included Content Delivery api & Content Search api both.
Here's the code included within Startup for both Content Delivery & Search api

```
context.Services.Configure<ContentApiSearchConfiguration>(config =>
        {
            config.Default()
            .SetMaximumSearchResults(200);
        });

        context.Services.Configure<ContentApiConfiguration>(config =>
        {
            config.Default()
            .SetMinimumRoles(string.Empty)
            .SetSiteDefinitionApiEnabled(true)
            .SetMultiSiteFilteringEnabled(true)
            .SetIncludeMasterLanguage(false)
            .SetFlattenPropertyModel(true)
            .SetValidateTemplateForContentUrl(false)
            .SetIncludeNullValues(false);
        });
    }
```

Content Delivery api works as expected. Here's a few ways to get  that i am getting the responses

Friendly Urls

http://example.com/executive-insights

http://example.com/executive-insights?expand=*

Content Id with ancestors & children

http://example.com/api/episerver/v2.0/content/20179

http://example.com/api/episerver/v2.0/content/20179/ancestors

http://example.com/api/episerver/v2.0/content/20179?expand=*

http://example.com/api/episerver/v2.0/content/20179/children

Content guid with ancestors
http://example.com/api/episerver/v2.0/content/8b308f72-87d4-4295-94bd-98177765797b

http://example.com/api/episerver/v2.0/content/8b308f72-87d4-4295-94bd-98177765797b/ancestors

Content Url
http://example.com/api/episerver/v2.0/content?contentUrl=http://example.com/executive-insights

http://example.com/api/episerver/v2.0/content?contentUrl=http://example.com/executive-insights&expand=*

Query:
**Is there a way to get the content api to return multiple pages json response?**

Problem area with Filters:
Filter criteria always return 0 matching records even when there are records available for the filter criterias:

Here's a few urls with filter criterias

http://example.com/api/episerver/v2.0/search/content?expand=*&personalize=true&filter=ContentType%2Fany%28t%3At%20ne%20%27LinkListFooterBlock%27%29%0D%0A&query=abc
http://example.com/api/episerver/v2.0/search/content?expand=*&filter=ContentType%2Fany%28t%3At%20ne%20%27LinkListFooterBlock%27%29%0D%0A&query=abc

Is there anything missing with filter criteria?
Any input is appreciated.

P.S: I do have an an active Episerver Find & also ran reindexing schedule job before querying the filter urls.